# Nested Collection Using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 table `Tab1` and `Tab2`.

Mapping of "`Tab1`" to "`Tab2`" is `one-to-many`.

Code is like that :

```
private Collection< Tab2 > obj = new ArrayList< Tab2 >();

@javax.persistence.OneToMany(fetch=javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY,
                                                     mappedBy = "Tab1")

public Collection< Tab2 > getTab2() 
{ 
  return Tab2;
}

public void setTab2( Collection<Tab2 > val ) 
{ 
 this.Tab2 = val;
}
```

I want to fetch record from both table.

**For example :** 
`Tab1` has column: 
`Stu_Id, Stu_FirstName, Stu_LastName` 

`Tab2` has column: 
`Stu_Id(foriegn Key),Stu_Subject, Stu_Teacher`

Now I want to fetch `Stu_id` from `Tab1` and `Stu_Subject`,`Stu_Teacher` from `Tab2`

Comment: I want to retrieve records by using JPA..

Answer (score 0):

You have different possibilities to solve your problem. Either you call a named query or you build your typed query with the [`CriteriaBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html)

There are already lots of other questions dealing with `OneToMany`-relations with either `NamedQuery` or `CriteriaBuilder`. It now depends on what you prefer. I personally prefer `CriteriaBuilder` due to the JPA-Metamodel you can use and the refactoring convenience it gives. (even though I wrote my own Wrapper to the `CriteriaBuilder` to get a better `SQL`-look-and-feel ;-))

Example for `NamedQuery`:
[Construct JPA query for a OneToMany relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564550/construct-jpa-query-for-a-onetomany-relation)

Example for `TypedQuery`:
[JPA CriteriaQuery OneToMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445426/jpa-criteriaquery-onetomany)